# How to move an unknown object to center screen? HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am developing a VueJS project and have created a set of cards appearing on the page, when one of these cards is selected, I wish for it to move to centre screen but keep the position it has moved from in the list of options.

I know that by changing the position from `'unset'` to `'relative'` the card now has move functionality with `'left'`, `'top'` etc. but I still need to find a way to automatically move the card to centre screen regardless of where on the screen the card is moving from.

Does anyone know how to achieve this with the use of JS?

I imagine there is a way of receiving the current location of the node and moving it to the center of the screen, but I am not sure on the specifics of how to achieve it...

Image for context:
[CardsProject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gffRC.png)

EDIT: I have for now gone with rendering an absolute position for the card which means there's no CSS transition from the card's original place to the centre of the screen and the card also temporarily loses its place within the deck.

Before click: [click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbXH3.jpg)

After click: [click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Assjr.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after many, many hours of scouring the internet and deepfrying my code.

The answer: ***Don't use 'relative' positioning!***

There's a far nice option to hold the position the element is moving from, but allow for the item to move freely with the use of CSS' `top` or `left` etc. and this option is `position:sticky;`!

With this and the use of [JavaScript's coordinates documentation](https://javascript.info/coordinates)

```
    .getBoundingClientRect()
```

...I managed to solve the mystery. The function I made to pull a vector between the current object and it the centre of the screen can be found here, returning an array of size 2 of X and Y vectors respectively.

```
  function calcCenterMove(element){

    /*
    X and Y are the current position of the element to be moved (top left corner).
    Width and Height are the width and height of the element to be moved.
    CX and CY are the X and Y coordinates of the centre of the screen.
    */

    var x       = element.getBoundingClientRect().x;
    var y       = element.getBoundingClientRect().y;
    var width   = element.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    var height  = element.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    var cx      = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var cy      = window.innerHeight / 2;
    var xVector = cx-(width/2)-x;
    var yVector = cy-(height/2)-y;
    return [xVector, yVector];
  }
  var xAxisMove = calcCenterMove(element)[0];
  var yAxisMove = calcCenterMove(element)[1];
  element.style =   "transform: translate("+xAxisMove+"px,"+yAxisMove+"px);";
```

I have paired the above code with a z-index to place the element above all others, and a screen dimming cover, to prevent the user from scrolling elsewhere or interacting with any other options.

Issues still arise here if the user resizes the screen, but I believe that is a different issue to address, possibly by using an event listener to assess a window resize and translate the element from the previous centre to the new centre using the same `cx` and `cy` properties above (or perhaps even the entire function!).

Nevertheless, I have come to the answer I was looking for, anyone feel free to use the code above, if needed!

Here are images for reference:

*[Before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dDlG.jpg)*

*[After click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0LS0.jpg)*

Regards!